# Different font rendering between Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, fonts, smoothing

With the new update of Firefox (Quantum) I decided to do switch between Chrome and Firefox
Meanwhile, I noticed some differences in font rendering between the two browsers.

[image]

The CSS used in these two browsers is strictly identical, but the "smooth" renderring is totally different.
Do you know what browser parameter could cause this? (I'm trying to have a render similar to Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Solution found, finally...

Go to address

> about:config

then change `gfx.font_rendering.cleartype_params.gamma` to `4`

You can also change contrast with `gfx.font_rendering.cleartype_params.enhanced_contrast`.

For testing purposes, I suggest you to have a window with text on a side of your screen, and the about:config page on an other side